# Replace object property inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to rename the icon for every object in an array to uppercase and replace `-` by `_`.

Array:

```
[
{time: 1566255600, summary: "Delno oblačno čez dan.", icon: "partly-cloudy-day", sunriseTime: 1566276904, sunsetTime: 1566328534, …},
{time: 1566342000, summary: "Pretežno oblačno čez dan.", icon: "partly-cloudy-day", sunriseTime: 1566363400, sunsetTime: 1566414810, …},
{time: 1566428400, summary: "Pretežno oblačno čez dan.", icon: "partly-cloudy-day", sunriseTime: 1566449896, sunsetTime: 1566501085, …},
{time: 1566514800, summary: "Pretežno oblačno čez dan.", icon: "partly-cloudy-day", ....}
]
```

```
const daysForecast = forecast.daily.data;  //api call that reterun array with object

var daysForecastNewIcon = [];


daysForecast.forEach(function(item){

  item.icon.replace(/-/g,"_").toUpperCase();

  daysForecastNewIcon.push(item)
});
```

Comment: You need to store the result of `.toUpperCase()`, something like `item.icon = item.icon.replace(/-/g,"_").toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
const daysForecast = forecast.daily.data.map(obj => { obj.icon = obj.icon.replace(/-/, "_").toUpperCase(); return obj });
```

Comment: Please Mark it as correct answer if someone will look for answer later :) glad to help :)